# Output filesize is too big when using gdal warp in Python

Tags: python, gdalwarp

I'm trying to process a very large directory of smaller geotiff files into a single mosaic. The cumulative size of the entire set of files is < 300mb but there are about 6,000 individual files around 5-15kb each. I'm trying to use gdal warp to process about 1/10 of the files at a time (so around 600 files at a time). The size of each batch is about 3mb, but the output file from warp is about 2.6gb. Is there any way to have the output file resemble the size of the inputs?

Here is an example of the code I am using so far:

```
i = 0
b = 1
tstep = int(len(mergeTiffs) / 10) #mergeTiffs is a list of file paths to the files to be merged
while tstep < ((len(mergeTiffs) + 1) - i):
  batchOut = 'batch_' + str(b) + '.tif'
  tiffBatch = mergeTiffs[i:i+tstep]
  gdal.Warp(batchOut, tiffBatch, srcNodata=-999.0, dstNodata=-999.0, warpMemoryLimit=1500)
  i = i + tstep + 1
  b = b + 1
```

Comment: Try https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html and warp the resulting vrt. Use compression options https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html and of course tiling for getting a result that is fast to use.

Comment: @user30184 I'm a bit of a noob, how do I reference the gtiff driver in python? I've looked all over the documentation and can't find anything helpful. For example, if I wanted to use LZW compression.

Comment: You can find usable examples from the GDAL autotests, for example this one about deflate dompression https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gcore/tiff_write.py#L229.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @user30184, I was able to form a solution based on the links you shared. I ended up not using Warp as the combination of BuildVRT and Transform was more memory efficient and resulted in a smaller file size. Here's an example of my solution:

```
t_options = gdal.TranslateOptions(format='GTiff', creationOptions=['TILED=YES', 'COMPRESS=LZW'])
i = 0
b = 1
step = int(len(unmerged_Tiffs)/10)
while step < ((len(unmerged_tiffs) + 1) - i):
  batchOut=batchDir+'/batch_'+str(b)+'.tif'
  VRTout=batchDir+'/batch_'+str(b)+'.vrt'
  tiffBatch=mergeTiffs[i:i+step]
  batchVRT=gdal.BuildVRT(VRTout,tiffBatch,srcNodata=-999.0,VRTNodata=-999.0)
  batchVRT.FlushCache()
  gdal.Translate(batchOut,batchVRT,options=t_options)
  i=i+step+1
  b=b+1
```